# How to set pixels to a Bitmap in android properly?

Tags: java, android, colors, bitmap, pixel

I want to save a pixelarray to a Bitmap.
I got everything working except: my app saves the bitmap, but the colors are a little bit different as they are in my array.

This is how I save the colors array:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
bitmap.setPixels(colors, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
OutputStream out = null;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getParent(), "new.png");
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is how I set a color to a pixel in the array:

```
colors[0] = 0x287026;
```

What goes wrong? The compression to a PNG and store it into my documents?
Because when I go to my documents on my phone and check the new PNG created, it's a little bit blurry.
Or is this bit of code wrong: Bitmap.Config.RGB_565? Do I need to use ARGB instead of just RGB?

Hope someone is able to help me! :)
Any help is appreciated!

Joeri

Comment: In what format is the `colors` array? My guess is that the pixels you're feeding it don't match the storage method you specified (`RGB_565`).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. Try use Bitmap.Config ARGB_8888 . Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 store each pixel only 2Bytes whereas ARGB_8888 stores each pixels 4 bytes. And Let me know if this worked.

Comment: My format of the colors array is int[], i feed them an hexadecimal number @cmbasnett

Comment: @mubeen Yes thank you very much! This worked!

Comment: @Joeri Good to hear that :) .. You are welcome very much

Answer (score 1):

Colors are encoded ints, and they can include the alpha channel.  I suspect your colors do include the alpha channel so you are using ARGB colors when your Bitmap format calls for RGB.  Change your image format to ARGB_8888 which is the default and recommended format.